# Treat uninitialized values as 0

Tags: game-maker

Does Gamemaker have a way to treat uninitialized values as 0?

Comment: Although the option is available, like Byte56 said, I strongly discourage its use, since it will create problems with typos. Always initialize necessary variables in the "Create" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameMaker has an option to turn on "Treat uninitialized variables as 0" in the error options. See the documentation [here](http://gamemaker.info/en/manual/302_05_errors).